# Watson IOT Out node on Raspberry Pi repeatedly disconnecting

Tags: raspberry-pi, ibm-cloud, iot, node-red, watson-iot

I am using a Watson IOT Output (wiotp out) in a Node-RED flow on my Raspberry PI and am having issues with the connection repeatedly disconnecting and then re-connecting.

Here is a screenshot of my [Credentials Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Oi7.png) and one of my [IOT Out Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0PWB.png).

The connection is configured so that I can send messages to the cloud and successfully have them trigger a flow in my cloud Node-RED instance.

The problem I'm having is that when I attempt to send a string array as my payload, very items in the array actually make it through before the service disconnects. I am limited to around 3-5 strings at a time, which is frustrating because I am losing 195-197 of the 200 items I am trying to send to the IOT platform.

How can I keep a persistent connection and make sure my entire payload makes it through to the IOT service?

Comment: you should start first from the NodeRed console on the raspberry and check what logs do say about the disconnections. Ben's indication can be one of the reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing very frequent disconnects, it can often mean that you're inadvertently performing clientId stealing (i.e., two MQTT clients are fighting over the same clientId). You can confirm this by looking at the device connection logs in the device drilldown panel: you'll see evidence of log messages such as "The client ID was reused."

Ben