# Watson IOT Out and In nodes alternating status

Tags: watson-iot

Related to that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50427550/watson-iot-out-node-on-raspberry-pi-repeatedly-disconnecting):

My wiotp out node is on a RPi, the wiotp in node on IBM Cloud. They can connect to the platform using the same credentials, but only one of them is connected, disconnecting after some seconds and vice versa.

What needs to be changed so both remain connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your two clients are using the same MQTT clientId, then they will fight over the same connection. Could that be happening here?