# Don't receive from wiotp

Tags: watson-iot

I'm sending events to the Watson IoT platform using the **wiotp out** node on a RPi, the event name is *eventfromasset*.

The **wiotp in** node on the IBM Cloud is connected to the same organization, but doesn't get any event.

I tried **all commands** and **specific command** = *eventfromasset*.

I do receive events using the IBM IoT node and API key/token instead.

Comment: have you specified the device type/id in the wiotp node?

Comment: yes, both are different than in the out node

Comment: WIoT log of the receiving device says "The connection has completed normally" after sending an event. It might have to do with the format of the event type?

Comment: if you subscribe to the command topic you need to use the same deviceid and the same devicetype for which you send the command. One note here, the command and events do not use the same topic path:
Devices can subscribe to command topics in the following format:

iot-2/cmd/command_id/fmt/format_string and Devices publish to the event topics in the following format:



iot-2/evt/event_id/fmt/format_string

Comment: thx, but I don't understand that as a had a problem using the same deviceid, pls. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886475/watson-iot-out-and-in-nodes-alternating-status

Comment: not the same scenario if you use the IoT nodes. They use different clientid that what the mqtt nodes are using. maybe we can have a talk and clarify things a little bit.